# How to typecast 'System.__ComObject' to recordset or dataset?

Tags: c#, ms-access, office-interop, oledbcommand, oledbdataadapter

I have written c# code to call ms access function.
 Below is the function call “`CallModule`” written in c# .

There is a function called “`fReturnRecordset`” in ms access. This function returns Recordset.

From c# we are able to call function successfully. 
But we are not able to typecast oRrecordSet object to recordset or dataset.

I get following error :

`“Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'ADODB.Recordset'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00001556-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).”`

Whenever I try the typasting.(see the commented line in the code i.e `//Recordset rs=(Recordset)oRrecordSet;`
)

ms access function :

```
Public Function fReturnRecordset() As Recordset
     Dim MyDB As DAO.Database
     Dim MyRS As DAO.Recordset
     Dim strSQL As String
     strSQL = "Select * From Customers Order by ContactName;"
     Set MyDB = CurrentDb
     Set MyRS = MyDB.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
     Set fReturnRecordset = MyRS
End Function
```

c# code :

```
public void CallModule()
    {
        try{
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application oAccess = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
        oAccess.Visible = true;
        oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"Path to accdb", false);
        object oRrecordSet = oAccess.Run("fReturnRecordset");
        //Recordset rs=(Recordset)oRrecordSet;
        oAccess.DoCmd.Quit(AcQuitOption.acQuitSaveNone);
        oAccess = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

How to do typecasting of the returned object, to recordset or dataset to fill the grid.

Comment: Where does `ADODB.Recordset` become involved?

Comment: object oRrecordSet = oAccess.Run("fReturnRecordset");

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand.  Within `fReturnRecordset`, the recordset is a `DAO.Recordset`.  But somehow trying to access that from c#, the error complains about an `ADODB.Recordset`.  `DAO` and `ADODB` recordsets are different object types.  If you run the function inside an independant Access application session does it return a `DAO.Recordset` or an `ADODB.Recordset`?

Comment: Yes, this is where I am stuck. My function returns DAO.Recordset. And on c# side I want to fetch that recordset. I want to display this data in the data grid.

Comment: Is this incorrect approach ? . If there is any other way then please suggest me. 
I want to make c# call to a procedure or function written in module of ms-access and display the returned data i.e recordset on data grid of c# code.

Answer (score 1):

Above approach is correct. It needs some more code to iterate through the recordset to fill the data table object.

```
public DataTable CallModule()
    {
        try{
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application oAccess = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
        oAccess.Visible = false;
        oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(DataBase, false);
        dao.Recordset oRecordSet = oAccess.Run("fReturnRecordset");

        oRecordSet.OpenRecordset();

       //------------------------------------
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("OriginalName");
        dt.Columns.Add("ModifiedName");

        while (!oRecordSet.EOF )
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["OriginalName"] = Convert.ToString(oRecordSet.Fields[0].Value);
            dr["ModifiedName"] = Convert.ToString(oRecordSet.Fields[1].Value);
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            oRecordSet.MoveNext();
        }

        oRecordSet.Close();

        oAccess.DoCmd.Quit(AcQuitOption.acQuitSaveNone);

        oAccess = null;

        return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```